# Catkin conversion: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPACKAGE_NAME

Tags: catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert some packages to catkin from rosbuild but one of my packages, "clam_controller", keeps getting the error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclam_controller

Which appears to me to be trying to link against itself. Nothing else is yet linking to this library - nothing depends on clam_controller yet.

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I have tried everything I could in tweaking my new [CMakeLists.txt](https://gist.github.com/4254423). The super simple old rosbuild script is [here](https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam/blob/master/clam_controller/CMakeLists.txt).

I'm on Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50120/catkin-conversion:-/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find--lpackage_name/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your CMakeLists your telling it to link against that:

```
target_link_libraries(joint_state_aggregator 
  ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

just remove ${PROJECT_NAME}

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2012-12-10**:
that'll do it, thanks!